# How can push the table of content to page 2 in the Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, data-science, pdflatex

[image]

```
---
title: "Thshe"
author: \textcolor{blue}{tEx Ty}
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%d-%B-%Y")`'
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: lualatex
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    latex_engine: xelatex     
linkcolor: black
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: margin = 1.2in
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{center}
  - \posttitle{\end{center}}
    \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{C:/Users/User/Downloads/download.png}\LARGE\\}
---

\centering
\raggedright
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

Above is my R code